# Trying to access mode 22 data

Tags: chrysler, obd

I'm trying to get mode 22 diagnostic data from my 2006 Chrysler Sebring 2.7L and more specifically the misfire counts for each cylinder. I have an ELM327 that I'm using. My car uses the J1850 VPW protocol. I am able to read functional addresses with out any issues (modes $01,$02,$03,$04,$05 etc) but for the life of me I can't seem to read anything from any physical address (modes $10 - $AE).

I found online that the misfire count data for my car should be in mode $22 PID $0777. The ID for my PCM is $10 and so in my ELM327 I set the 3 byte header to 24 10 F1 and for the data portion I send 220777 but the ELM returns NO DATA. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I set F1 for the transmit ID as F1 - FD are designated for scan tools though I suspect Chrysler might only accept requests from a special transmit ID? Also I'm not 100% sure I am sending the correct header byte. I'm using 24 as the header byte since I found it online and it makes sense when decoded (00010100) which is set for physical addressing mode.

I know my car records misfire data because a friend of mine has a fairly expensive scan tool that reads it from my car. Its not a factory tool though so I'm sure I should be able to access the misfire counts with my ELM327.

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I’m not really familiar with how it all works but I can say per a Chrysler mode 6 datasheet that the scaling ID is 24 the obdmid is a2-9 or a2-7 in your case and the TID for last/current drive cyles is 0c.

Comment: I believe the mode 6 misfire data you mention is for CAN protocol only and not for older J1850 protocols. My mode 6 gives totally different PIDs when scanned. The misfire data should be in mode 22 but I can't seem to get it out.

Comment: sorry to bring up an old thread. Do you know what PIDs give your fault code (DTCs). I know mode 03 and 07. I am asking about the manufacturer specific PIDs for DTCs.